# get Windows Phone 7.1 Device ID

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

We implement the PUSH NOTIFICATION on Windows Phone 7.1 and we need to register the link to server to be able to push. and we also support for update the link in case where the apps is uninstall and re-install. new link will be saved to server for the same device. So we try to get the device ID of the device to identify and update the link instead of saving a new one for the same device.

Since

```
DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueID", out uniqueID)
```

is not allowed for Windows Phone 7.1. Is there any other solution to get a unique ID for a device ?

we can't use account live to identify the phone since a user can use many device using only one live account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the DeviceID. You need to include this in your WMAppManifest.xml 
`<Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE" />`

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Capabilities)

Comment: yes it already there but the problem is that Windows Phone 7.1 Mango DeviceExtendedProperties is deprecated. So it won't allowed as in 7.0

Comment: Hi, in the remark on the msdn page, it's written "In Windows Phone OS 7.0, this class was used to query device-specific properties. In Windows Phone OS 7.1, most of the properties in DeviceExtendedProperties were deprecated, and the new DeviceStatus class should be used instead. However, where appropriate, you can still use any of the below properties that are not deprecated."
I guess you can still use DeviceExtendedProperties's DeviceUniqueID !

Comment: Yes we can still use but accord to this link on WindowsPhoneGeek http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-7-vs-Windows-Phone-Mango-Getting-Device-Information they show it work (perhaps on phone with OS 7.0 only ). my current device is on 7.1, still can't make it work even deploy an app builded for 7.0 on device 7.1.

Comment: OK I make it work now. may be I use a wrong code. after implement the code from Windowsphonegeek.com it work :)

Answer (score 1):

Use "DeviceUniqueId" instead of "DeviceUniqueID".